# creating custom roles in Cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, roles

We have a requirement of having custom roles in cloud foundry.Having gone through the documentation I can see custom roles are not supported by CF ,but can we modify the existing roles to be more restrictive as per our usage.

Our use case is as follows:-
Relevant permissions:
1.  deploy applications
2.  (re)start/stop applications
3.  access application logs
4.  bind cf services to applications
a.  market place services, e.g. MySQL
b.  user-provided services, e.. for storing access credentials of external services on AWS
5.  create/update cf services, e.g. set access credentials
6.  view cf service settings via the cf command line interface, e.g. see unencrypted passwords
Defining roles and permissions is tightly integrated with the intended work processes.
In a DevOps I would suggest the following:
•   Role DevOp
o   permissions 1, 2, 3, 4
•   Role Admin
o   permissions 5, 6

Answer (score 1):

There is no as such customization available with cloud foundry.

I would suggest you to read below table for existing roles and permission and assign according to your need.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/roles.html